# Creating a SQL view that will accept inserted values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a SQL view that retrieves the result set I desire but when I try to add a new set of values it fails. When searching around on the net it appears that VIEW has a few limitations and some types of joins may not be allowed, I have tried to create the view a few different ways but with no success yet, would anyone happen to know a way I could rewrite this create view query that would allow me to insert new values into it?

The view:

```
CREATE VIEW NATIONAL_ITEMS 
AS
    SELECT item.itemno, item.itemdesc, item.itemprice
    FROM item 
    FULL OUTER JOIN invoiceitem ON item.itemno = invoiceitem.itemno
    WHERE item.itemdesc LIKE '%National%' 
      AND invoiceitem.invoiceno IS NULL
    WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

My insert statement that does not work:

```
INSERT INTO NATIONAL_ITEMS 
VALUES ('123-456', 'National TV', 100);
```

I get this error:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
> INSERT INTO NATIONAL_ITEMS VALUES ('123-456', 'National TV', 100)
> Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 1
> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here
> 01733. 00000 -  "virtual column not allowed here"

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can simply insert into the base tables or create an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view, that sorts things out and does that for you when you insert into the view.

Comment: Is one of the columns used in the view definition a virtual column?

Comment: Your view doesn't have 1:1 relationship with the driving table. You cannot INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE on it.

Comment: Your query doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  You're doing a `full outer join` but then you have a predicate on `item.itemdesc` that makes it effectively a `left outer join`.  What data would you want to appear in `invoiceitem` after you do the `insert`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options for the view in order to insert in the view.

First, Your View must contain all the keys present in the table on which you are creating the view i.e there must be no `DISTINCT` OR `GROUP BY` clause.

If you performing `JOIN` on the tables same is applicable for all join tables, all keys from the table must be present in the view and there must be no `DISTINCT` OR `GROUP BY` clause.

The table which has 1:1 row relationship with the rows in the view called `Key preserving table`

Second, you can create instead of trigger on the view. The trigger will be fired instead of `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, OR `DELETE` and in the trigger, you can handle the DML statement.

Since your table is not key preserving then you can make use of `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NATIONAL_ITEMS_TRG
INSTEAD OF INSERT
ON NATIONAL_ITEMS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ITEM(itemno, itemdesc, itemprice) VALUES (:NEW.itemno, :NEW.itemdesc, :NEW.itemprice);
END;
```

Comment: Thankyou, this allows me to insert what I needed. Just curious, how would I go about the other method you mentioned with 'key preserving'?

Comment: Suppose you created a view something like CREATE VIEW vw as SELECT department_id, SUM(salary) sum FROM EMPLOYEES; Now you want to insert a row in this VIEW but data is not actual data present in the table and view is summarized and has a derived column sum using the aggregate function. But if you do something simple like CREATE VIEW vw as SELECT employee_id,  first_name, salary FROM employess;  so the table and view have 1:1 row relationship and it is clear whatever row you update or insert or delete in view has corresponding single row in table. No ambiguity.

Comment: That does not mean you can not use predicate, it simply means whatever row you have in your view should have a 1:1 relationship with a row in the table. If you have multiple tables in the view then the same goes for all tables in the view all rows in the view must have 1:1 relationship and it can be by adding a key column of the join table.